# Typhoon - How to inject parameter which conforms to PROTOCOL instead of CLASS

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, typhoon

I have class which represents logged user

```
public class User: NSObject {        
    init(authenticator: Authenticator) {        
        self.authenticator = authenticator
    }
    ... 
}
```

Its only initial arguments is object which conforms to **Authenticator protocol**

```
protocol Authenticator
{
    func authenticate(login:String , password:String , handler: (result:AuthenticationResult)->()  )
}
```

In my case the Auth object is instance of class **BackendService**

My typhoon assembly definition is:

```
public dynamic func user() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(User.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.useInitializer("initWithAuthenticator") {
            (initializer) in

            initializer.injectParameterWith( self.backendService() )
        }            
    }
}
```

Application cause **runtime-error**

```
'Method 'initWithAuthenticator' has 0 parameters, but 1 was injected. Do you mean 'initWithAuthenticator:'?'
```

If i change init method to 'initWithAuthenticator:' it crashes with

```
'Method 'initWithAuthenticator:' not found on 'PersonalMessages.User'. Did you include the required ':' characters to signify arguments?'
```

Comment: if init method is changed to `init(authenticator:BackendService)` it works fine

Comment: Problem is caused because of swift protocol hasn't `@obj` keyword

Answer (score 1):

At the present time, it is necessary to add the '@objc' directive to Swift protocols to have them be available for dependency injection with Typhoon. Without it the objective-c runtime's introspection and dynamic dispatch features arent available and these are required.

Similarly, in the case of a class it must extend from NSObject or have the '@objc' directive, otherwise it will also use C++ style vtable dispatch and have (essentially) no reflection. In the case of private vars or methods, they must also have the 'dynamic' modifier.

While vtable dispatch is faster, it prevents runtime method interception which many of Cocoa's most powerful features, such as KVO rely on. So both paradigms are important and its impressive that Swift can switch between them. In the case of protocols though, using the '@objc' directive is a little unfortunate as it implies a 'legacy' behavior. Perhaps 'dynamic' would've been better?

```
dynamic protocol Authenticator //Not supported but would've been a nicer than '@objc'?
```

Or perhaps another way to imply that dynamic behavior is required would be to have the protocol extend the NSObject protocol, however this does not work. So using '@objc' is the only choice.

Meanwhile, for classes the requirement to extend NSObject isn't really noticible as far as working with Cocoa/Touch apps goes.